# How to avoid Visual Studio 2022 to add project configuration to output path

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 is adding subfolders to the base output path.

Is there a way to prevent it from adding Release/Debug subfolders to the output path?

[Visual Studio 2022 - Project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhr03.png)

Comment: these folders are there to distinguish between the release and debug configuration of your build. regardless, if you are planning on doing only a single config build of your project, you could try what's shown in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022). just replace the [build]/[debug] subfolder from the output path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Mubin. The documentation doesn't match up with my visual studio project's configuration though. At Build>Output>Base output path, I have set my directory with no build/release subfolder.
That folder is added later on based on the configuration.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the full solution based on [Microsoft's Debugger Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2022):

1. Click on Project > [name of project]
2. In Build > Output, change the Base output path to C:\ [full directory path] \ [name of project]
3. Click on Project > Edit Project File
4. Add to `PropertyGroup>`
   `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>`
   `<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>`
   `<OutputPath>C:\[full directory path]\[name of project]</OutputPath>`

Comment: Make sure that OutputPath is **after** the Appends

Answer (score 4):

The output path is a concatenation of a bunch of MSBuild properties.  Depending on your project type, it can happen in the project file, in a targets file you import explicitly, or in an implicit import such as via an MSBuild SDK.  In any of these cases, you should be able to override it by setting the value explicitly in your project file.

Taking the 3rd case as an example (using the Microsoft.NET.Sdk), in Microsoft.NET.DefaultOutputPaths.targets you'll find the defaults specified like this:

```
    <BaseOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseOutputPath)' == ''">bin\</BaseOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath Condition="!HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseOutputPath)')">$(BaseOutputPath)\</BaseOutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)' == '' and '$(PlatformName)' == 'AnyCPU'">$(BaseOutputPath)$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)' == '' and '$(PlatformName)' != 'AnyCPU'">$(BaseOutputPath)$(PlatformName)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="!HasTrailingSlash('$(OutputPath)')">$(OutputPath)\</OutputPath>
```

Notice how the `$(OutputPath)` is basically appending the `$(Configuration)` to the `$(BaseOutputPath)`.

If you want to always have the same output path, you can set `<OutputPath>Your\Desired\Path</OutputPath>` in your project file.  Once you've set the value, this default logic above will be skipped based on the now-false condition (`'$(OutputPath)'` is no longer empty).

**However, this may break incremental build** if you build different configurations without deleting the contents of the output folder between builds.

Answer (score 2):

In my case - with a Nunit test project it didn't help either. The **Debug** and **Release** folders were always created.
I had to make the following changes in the project file:
From:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <BaseOutputPath>bin\</BaseOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to:
(add the two false values and BaseOutputPath --> OutputPath and BaseIntermediateOutputPath --> IntermediateOutputPath)

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```